# Gitlab manual jobs causing pipeline to be Blocked

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a 'report' stage at the end of my Gitlab CI/CD pipeline and have now added some static analysis jobs to run only when the `RUN_ANALYSIS` environment variable is set to "true":

```
RunAnalysis:
  stage: report
  needs: []
  rules:
    - if: $RUN_ANALYSIS == "true"
      when: always
    - if: $RUN_ANALYSIS != "true"
      when: manual
  script:
    - .\RunAnalysis.ps1
```

In my branch pipeline, this was fine, the job was manual, and the pipeline would succeed. I was running the branch on a schedule with the `RUN_ANALYSIS` environment variable set to "true" and this was also fine with the above job run automatically and the pipeline succeeding.

Now the pipeline is running in `master`. All the other jobs pass, the analysis job is set to manual since there is no `RUN_ANALYSIS` environment variable, yet the pipeline status finishes as 'Blocked'. Why does it do that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pipeline status will be blocked until the manual job is run -- that's what the blocked status means: running a manual job is necessary for the pipeline to continue.

You might be able avoid this if you set `allow_failure: true` because pipeline stages won't be blocked by manual jobs that allow failure.

Reference: 'additional details' in the [when keyword documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when) and [allow_failure documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure)

Comment: Previously this job was set to manual and didn't cause the pipeline status to be Blocked. Why does adding these rules now cause the pipeline status to be Blocked?

Comment: @DLT because the behavior is different when using `rules:when:` and just `when:` -- this is mentioned in the 'additional details' section I linked. In the latter case, `allow_failure: true` is implied, but not with `rules:when:`